# Date fromat in datepicker primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

Im using primeng datepicker but im getting this error:

> Unexpected literal at position 2

This is format that im trying to use:

```
2018-06-13 00:00:00"
```

Any suggestion? i need to use this format.

Comment: Please provide more details on how you are trying to use it and some code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert received date string  to Date:

```
this.AnnouncementDate = new Date(this.AnnouncementDate);
```

and bind it